# Open GUI of Mac applications of other user accounts

Tags: macos, user-accounts, microsoft-teams, microsoft

I want to run multiple Microsoft Teams on Mac Os. Teams don't provide the functionality to add multiple organizations in the app, its web app is not that good. So tried various combinations to run multiple instances of the Teams app, and even tried copying the "Teams.app" in the Applications folder with another name. I got a script that can run an application multiple times, and create a script file for that but it didn't work. Then I created another user account on my Mac M1 Pro, and logged in to Teams with another organization, it ran smoothly but I have to switch accounts to access other things. Then I got a script => `sudo -u <user-account> open /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app/Contents/MacOS/Teams`, the command worked but only opened my current instance of the application and not the one of another user.

All of the above methods seem to be opening the currently running instance of the Teams app where I have logged in with one of my accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this may be to set up two separate user accounts on the Mac. Run one instance in each. That way they will be truly separate, each will have its own prefs.

macOS is not designed to run more than one instance of an app concurrently by default. Even if you duplicate the app, each will still be reading & writing to the same prefs. The only way to truly enable this kind of separation is before compile, by design.

A very few apps are designed that you can specifically dictate your prefs name & location at launch, from script or command line; but this is quite rare & I wouldn't expect it of a major player like Microsoft. If anything, they would allow you to swap profiles, but it would be one at a time, not concurrently.

Comment: Yes, I use two separate user accounts for this purpose but surely I can not get the notification of the other account on my default one, so this direction doesn't make any sense in my case, I want to receive and reply to the messages on the default user-account only.

Comment: What you want is not possible unless the functionality is in the app itself.